# Impersonate User using spatie / laravel-google-calendar

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api

so i want send invitation email to attendees on an event created on google calendar. but when i did

```
use Spatie\GoogleCalendar\Event as GoogleCalendarEvent;

$calendarEvent = new GoogleCalendarEvent;

$calendarEvent->name = $event->title;
$calendarEvent->startDateTime = $event->start_date;
$calendarEvent->endDateTime = $event->end_date;
$calendarEvent->addAttendee(['email' => 'isley269@gmail.com']);

$calendarEvent->save();
```

I get error as

```
{ "error": 
    { "errors": [{ 
         "domain": "calendar", 
         "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts", 
         "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." 
    } ], 
     "code": 403, 
     "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." 
    } 
}
```

So I already gave a domain-wide authority to the service credential. But i am still getting the error because i tried to invite users using the service account. How can i impersonate a user using this service account in laravel 7 using Spatie\GoogleCalendar ?

I tried browsing google's api and Spatie's docs. but i can't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This issue has been already reported on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/141704931)

Currently, a service account is not allowed to invite attendees without impersonation.

In order to implement impersonation, you need to add the line

`$client->setSubject('SPECIFY HERE THE USER TO IMPERSONATE');`

when creating `new Google_Client()` with the service account.

See [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts) for more information.

Comment: i have the same problem, where i nee to add setSubject? Using spatie / laravel-google-calendar there is no need to do new Google_Client()

Comment: i'have modified the GoogleCalendarFactory of Using spatie / laravel-google-calendar adding $client->setSubject('user mail'); after new Google_Client(). The error returned is "{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." }"